# Mariadb failover VIP- check the host behind

Tags: linux, mysql, mariadb

During MariaDB failover our VIP didn't reflect the host change in UI which caused issues. Is there a way/command to check if the VIP got assigned new master host properly by any command? So that we don't have to roll back the changes. I tried pinging VIP but I think it always connects irrespective of any actual host behind it.

Comment: How exactly did you set up HA?

Comment: I don't have HA set up. we have automated failover to read replica in case of disaster. Also VIP is secured so cant connect to it, only way to interact is QLB commands

Comment: How exactly did you set up automated failover?

Comment: Is this AWS? What is the exact VIP mechanism.